# Как сделать два запроса через одно подключение PDO?

Tags: pdo, php_pdo, php, mysql

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, USER, PASSWORD);
$DBH->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
$postsH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC");

$posts = '';
while($row = $postsH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, USER, PASSWORD);
    $DB ->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
    $catH = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE `id` = '$row[cat]'");
    $cat = $catH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      
    $posts .= "$row[text], ";
}
```

В таком случае код работает. Если создать новый объект (new PDO).
Если же попробовать подключиться через старый объект, то возникает ошибка, запрос не удается, и нельзя использоваться fetch, потому что результатом запроса является false, а не объект. Как использовать первое подключение без создания нового?

Вот так не работает:

```
 while($row = $postsH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $catH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE `id` = '$row[cat]'");
    $cat = $catH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       
        $posts .= "$row[text], ";
    }
```

Comment: кто ж запросы в цикле выполняет? сделайте один запрос и бегите по нему.

Answer (score 1):

> Если после выполнения предыдущего запроса вы не выбрали все данные из результирующего набора, следующий вызов PDO::query() может потерпеть неудачу. В таких случаях следует вызываеть метод PDOStatement::closeCursor(), который освободит ресурсы базы данных занятые предыдущим объектом PDOStatement. После этого можно безопасно вызывать PDO::query().

Источник:  http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php